# How to notify a G+ circle?

Tags: google-plus

Is it possible to make a post which notifies the users who are in a circle I have shared it with?

I understand that this would be ridiculous if I was to share a post with a huge circle, but if I have a particular circle of friends who I wish to speak to, is there a way of notifying them without having to mention each user in the share every time?

Answer (score 4):

"Notify" in what way?

People can choose to be notified<sup>1</sup> by your posts (either you specifically or a Circle that they've put you in). But you're not in control; they are.

Elsewise, you can check a box to "also send email to {circlename}" which will do what it says, but a lot of people have been complaining about this feature being abused. (I've gotten my fair share of G+ spam from people I don't really care to hear from. It earned them a "blocked by Al" badge.)

Otherwise, no, you can't foist a notification on someone who would rather not be notified about your posts.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> In other words, get [Mr. Jingles](http://www.googleplusdaily.com/2013/06/exclusive-google-plus-daily-interviews.html) to alert them to the post in the Notifications panel.

<sup>2</sup> Unless you use the trick you've already discovered of including them *by name* instead of the Circle you have them in.

Comment: If I share a post with someone in particular, they get a notification (notification as in Mr. Jingles displays the post). If I share to a group, they don't

Comment: Exactly. _Unless_ they've chosen to receive notifications when you post.

Comment: In the beginning it was possible to click on a circle and select "notify" in a pop-up baloon, but it was since removed (as it was probably abused).